# Toggle insert/navigation modes by pressing insert key?

Tags: vim

By default when I press `insert` key, vim switches to the `INSERT` mode.
If I press `insert` key again, vim switches to the `REPLACE` mode.

I want to toggle **INSERT/NAVIGATION** modes by pressing `insert` key.

I.e.: press `insert` key -> get `INSERT` mode. Press `insert` key again -> get back `NAVIGATION` mode.

How do I get that?

Comment: If your insert key is `i` as default then second time it's start to typing 'i'.

Comment: I want to use `insert` key, not `i`.

Comment: That's "normal" mode, not "navigation" mode.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change the meaning of the `<Insert>` key (that's how it's spelled in Vim's key notation), you define an *insert mode mapping*. Since you want to leave insert mode, you map the key to `<Esc>`, which takes you out of insert mode.

```
:inoremap <Insert> <Esc>
```

Answer (score 2):

`imap <insert> <esc>`